# JSON can call method in .aspx file but not in .asmx (ASP.NET web service) file

Tags: asp.net, jquery, json, asmx

I am using JQuery & JSON (POST) to call webmethod. However I can call only webmethod located at aspx file but not in asmx file

Below are sample codes

CustomValidate.asmx

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel


Public Class CustomValidate
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

'ACCESS VIA JSON

<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function AJAX_Test(ByVal date1) As Boolean
...

    Return True
End Function
End Class
```

Javascript: JQuery JSON

```
function isDates(source, arguments) {
                var isValidDate;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "CustomValidate.asmx/AJAX_Test",
                    data: '{date1: "' + arguments.Value + '"}',
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function(result) {

                        isValidDate = result;
                    },
                    error: function(httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                       alert("status=" + textStatus + ",error=" + errorThrown);
                    } 

                });
                arguments.IsValid = isValidDate;
            }
```

It always return javascript undefined error. But if I put the AJAX_Test webmethod in aspx page and replace the url: "CustomValidate.asmx/AJAX_Test" to "mypage.aspx/AJAX_Test". It works fine. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using what is known as a "Page Method". That is, a static (Shared) method with a [WebMethod] attribute on it. These only work inside of an .ASPX page. They are intended to be used only by JavaScript running on the page.

Try removing the `Shared` from the method and see if it works better.